# Optimizing and caching frequently accessed but rarely updated Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, efficiency, caching

My app has some tables that will be rarely updated, probably just once in the beginning and at the system setup. Despite that, they will be frequently accessed. Almost every operation depends on querying them, but as I said they will not be changed.

I'm looking for advices for optimizing this web app.

I have defined indexes on most frequently searched columns. What else can I do? How should I cache this tables?

It's written in ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am more familiar with standard LAMP  stack or equivalent frameworks.

If you have exhausted all the optimizations you can do at the db level (including  enabling query caches etc..), you could cache the results using memcache or equivalent in the windows world.

As you have infrequent updates, it seems like a good candidate to use a cluster of memcache servers (to distribute the load) - it is a simple key-value store and memcached servers listen on tcp (or udp) sockets, and it is very easy to setup, debug etc..:

http://memcached.org/